# Reaching max participants on event price set results in WSOD

Tags: civievent, price-sets

I have an event that uses a price set and limits a price option in a price set to 7. Once it was reached, the event registration page results in WSOD. If I increase it, the page loads just fine. I recall this occuring to me months ago as well.

I am unable to properly test on https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ as it does not appear a registration in test mode counts against the participant count and I can't change this in the db directly. Is this just me or can others replicate?

Civi 5.35.2 WP 5.7.2

Ref: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues?scope=all&state=opened&search=max+participant

Comment: what stops you using non-test registration on the demo site?

Comment: want to use a price set with a real dollar amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed with the following:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/20073/commits/4a004c120d497f227165d98c81e828998fdd276c

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/event/-/issues/53